Nexthink NQL count users having MAC and Win devices
Is there a way in NQL to have one investigation giving you the total number of users having MAC and Windows devices?
something like ... user.[mac, windows]
I didn't find a way to connect these two tables. Was thinking somehow through the events table.

As you suspected, events is the way to do this.
execution.events during past 7d
| summarize number_of_users = user.count() by context.device_platform 


